# Solr ShingleFilterFactory auto-suggest

Tags: lucene, autosuggest, solr

I'm using Solr `ShingleFilterFactory` for auto-suggestion.
This is my field configuration :

```
<fieldType name="textSpellShingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And my query :

```
q=rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=spellingShingle&facet.prefix=har
```

I get these answers :

- **har**ry potter
- **har**rison ford
- etc...

The problem is when I search "pot" or "for"... I'm not getting any results. I'd like to suggest "**pot**ter harry" or "**for**d harrison".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the results are depending on the content of your field `spellingShingle`.
If both, "harry potter" and "potter harry" are values of the field, solr/lucene will return "potter harry"  by typing "pot"